# Bluetooth timed out

Tags: 12.04, bluetooth

I am using a desktop and having bluetooth dongle in a working condition.
Now the problem is I am having multiple problems at different combination which I had tried.
I have been through whole site searching for my problem.
Tried installing many thing but its all in vain.
At present I had installed blueman but it is also not working.
Result of `lsusb`

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04f3:0235 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

After installing blueman when I restarted the system there was an error showing like **bluetooth timed out** exacly before the ubuntu loads.

It would be very much appreciated if anyone will help me rather redirecting to any other post as I have been through all related post.Thank you.
At last now it has stopped  to this stage....
[image]

Each time I get a different error....Someone please help me...
[image: Resource not ready]

Another...
[image]

This is the syslog file of my system.....

> Dec 13 12:12:55 kamil-desktop rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd"
>   swVersion="5.8.6" x-pid="663" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"]
>   rsyslogd was HUPed Dec 13 12:13:29 kamil-desktop anacron[923]: Job
>   `cron.daily' terminated (mailing output) Dec 13 12:13:29 kamil-desktop
>   anacron[923]: Can't find sendmail at /usr/sbin/sendmail, not mailing
>   output Dec 13 12:13:29 kamil-desktop anacron[923]: Normal exit (1 job
>   run) Dec 13 12:17:01 kamil-desktop CRON[2586]: (root) CMD (   cd / &&
>   run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly) Dec 13 12:19:18 kamil-desktop
>   kernel: [  911.909542] audit_printk_skb: 15 callbacks suppressed Dec
>   13 12:19:18 kamil-desktop kernel: [  911.909550] type=1400
>   audit(1386917358.697:28): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable"
>   parent=1 profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=796 comm="cupsd" pid=796
>   comm="cupsd" capability=36  capname="block_suspend" Dec 13 13:01:07
>   kamil-desktop kernel: [ 3420.828023] usb 2-1: new full-speed USB
>   device number 3 using uhci_hcd Dec 13 13:01:07 kamil-desktop kernel: [
>   3420.982683] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0a12, idProduct=0001 Dec 13 13:01:07 kamil-desktop kernel: [ 3420.982691]
>   usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0 Dec
>   13 13:01:07 kamil-desktop bluetoothd[786]: HCI dev 0 registered Dec 13
>   13:01:07 kamil-desktop bluetoothd[786]: Listening for HCI events on
>   hci0 Dec 13 13:01:07 kamil-desktop kernel: [ 3421.029172] usbcore:
>   registered new interface driver btusb Dec 13 13:01:09 kamil-desktop
>   kernel: [ 3423.108013] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c12 tx timeout Dec
>   13 13:01:11 kamil-desktop kernel: [ 3425.112027] Bluetooth: hci0
>   command 0x0c01 tx timeout Dec 13 13:01:13 kamil-desktop kernel: [
>   3427.116014] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1002 tx timeout Dec 13 13:01:15 kamil-desktop kernel: [ 3429.120023] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c45 tx
>   timeout Dec 13 13:01:27 kamil-desktop bluetoothd[2863]: Can't init
>   device hci0: Connection timed out (110) Dec 13 13:08:55 kamil-desktop
>   avahi-daemon[794]: Registering new address record for
>   2002:1b74:3397:a:40bb:75ef:1320:8306 on eth0.*. Dec 13 13:08:55
>   kamil-desktop avahi-daemon[794]: Registering new address record for
>   2002:1b74:3397:a:219:d1ff:feac:e561 on eth0.*. Dec 13 13:10:09
>   kamil-desktop dbus[734]: [system] Reloaded configuration Dec 13
>   13:10:58  dbus[734]: last message repeated 7 times Dec 13 13:11:10
>   kamil-desktop bluetoothd[786]: HCI dev 0 unregistered Dec 13 13:11:10
>   kamil-desktop bluetoothd[786]: Stopping hci0 event socket Dec 13
>   13:11:10 kamil-desktop kernel: [ 4023.704057] usb 2-1: USB disconnect,
>   device number 3 Dec 13 13:11:13 kamil-desktop kernel: [ 4026.548024]
>   usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 2 using uhci_hcd Dec 13
>   13:11:13 kamil-desktop kernel: [ 4026.907079] usb 3-1: New USB device
>   found, idVendor=0a12, idProduct=0001 Dec 13 13:11:13 kamil-desktop
>   kernel: [ 4026.907086] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0,
>   Product=0, SerialNumber=0 Dec 13 13:11:13 kamil-desktop
>   bluetoothd[786]: HCI dev 0 registered Dec 13 13:11:13 kamil-desktop
>   bluetoothd[786]: Listening for HCI events on hci0 Dec 13 13:11:15
>   kamil-desktop kernel: [ 4028.944016] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1009 tx
>   timeout Dec 13 13:11:17 kamil-desktop kernel: [ 4030.948012]
>   Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1005 tx timeout Dec 13 13:11:19
>   kamil-desktop kernel: [ 4032.952022] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c23 tx
>   timeout Dec 13 13:11:21 kamil-desktop kernel: [ 4034.956020]
>   Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c14 tx timeout Dec 13 13:11:23
>   kamil-desktop bluetoothd[3529]: Can't init device hci0: Connection
>   timed out (110) Dec 13 13:11:53 kamil-desktop kernel: Kernel logging
>   (proc) stopped. Dec 13 13:11:53 kamil-desktop rsyslogd: [origin
>   software="rsyslogd" swVersion="5.8.6" x-pid="663"
>   x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] exiting on signal 15. Dec 13 13:12:48
>   kamil-desktop kernel: imklog 5.8.6, log source = /proc/kmsg started.
>   Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd"
>   swVersion="5.8.6" x-pid="664" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
>   Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop rsyslogd: rsyslogd's groupid changed to
>   103 Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop rsyslogd: rsyslogd's userid changed
>   to 101 Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop rsyslogd-2039: Could not open
>   output pipe '/dev/xconsole' [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2039 ] Dec
>   13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup
>   subsys cpuset Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000]
>   Initializing cgroup subsys cpu Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [
>   0.000000] Linux version 3.8.0-34-generic (buildd@toyol) (gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) ) #49~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Nov 13 18:05:00 UTC 2013 (Ubuntu 3.8.0-34.49~precise1-generic 3.8.13.12)
>   Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] Command line:
>   BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-34-generic
>   root=UUID=ad695616-caeb-451b-b8bf-707ba6232e39 ro quiet splash
>   vt.handoff=7 Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000]
>   KERNEL supported cpus: Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [
>   0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000]   Centaur CentaurHauls Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] e820: BIOS-provided physical RAM map: Dec 13 13:12:48
>   kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem
>   0x0000000000000000-0x000000000008efff] usable Dec 13 13:12:48
>   kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem
>   0x000000000008f000-0x000000000009ffff] reserved Dec 13 13:12:48
>   kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem
>   0x00000000000e0000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved Dec 13 13:12:48
>   kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem
>   0x0000000000100000-0x000000007e5f4fff] usable Dec 13 13:12:48
>   kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem
>   0x000000007e5f5000-0x000000007e6d0fff] ACPI NVS Dec 13 13:12:48
>   kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem
>   0x000000007e6d1000-0x000000007f573fff] usable Dec 13 13:12:48
>   kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem
>   0x000000007f574000-0x000000007f57bfff] reserved Dec 13 13:12:48
>   kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem
>   0x000000007f57c000-0x000000007f60afff] usable Dec 13 13:12:48
>   kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem
>   0x000000007f60b000-0x000000007f60efff] reserved Dec 13 13:12:48
>   kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem
>   0x000000007f60f000-0x000000007f6a7fff] usable Dec 13 13:12:48
>   kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem
>   0x000000007f6a8000-0x000000007f6e9fff] ACPI NVS Dec 13 13:12:48
>   kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem
>   0x000000007f6ea000-0x000000007f6edfff] usable Dec 13 13:12:48
>   kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem
>   0x000000007f6ee000-0x000000007f6fefff] ACPI data Dec 13 13:12:48
>   kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem
>   0x000000007f6ff000-0x000000007f6fffff] usable Dec 13 13:12:48
>   kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem
>   0x000000007f700000-0x000000007fffffff] reserved Dec 13 13:12:48
>   kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem
>   0x00000000fff80000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved Dec 13 13:12:48
>   kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] NX (Execute Disable) protection:
>   active Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] SMBIOS 2.5
>   present. Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] DMI:
>   /D945GCPE, BIOS PE94510M.86A.0069.2008.1204.1528 12/04/2008 Dec 13
>   13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] e820: update [mem
>   0x00000000-0x0000ffff] usable ==> reserved Dec 13 13:12:48
>   kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] e820: remove [mem
>   0x000a0000-0x000fffff] usable Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [ 
>   0.000000] No AGP bridge found Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] e820: last_pfn = 0x7f700 max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000 Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] MTRR default type:
>   uncachable Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] MTRR
>   fixed ranges enabled: Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [
>   0.000000]   00000-9FFFF write-back Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000]   A0000-FFFFF uncachable Dec 13 13:12:48
>   kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] MTRR variable ranges enabled: Dec
>   13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000]   0 base 000000000
>   mask F80000000 write-back Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [
>   0.000000]   1 base 07F800000 mask FFF800000 uncachable Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000]   2 base 07F700000 mask FFFF00000
>   uncachable Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000]   3
>   disabled Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000]   4
>   disabled Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000]   5
>   disabled Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000]   6
>   disabled Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000]   7
>   disabled Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] x86 PAT
>   enabled: cpu 0, old 0x7040600070406, new 0x7010600070106 Dec 13
>   13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] original variable MTRRs
>   Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] reg 0, base: 0GB,
>   range: 2GB, type WB Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [
>   0.000000] reg 1, base: 2040MB, range: 8MB, type UC Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] reg 2, base: 2039MB, range: 1MB,
>   type UC Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] total RAM
>   covered: 2039M Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000]
>   Found optimal setting for mtrr clean up Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop
>   kernel: [    0.000000]  gran_size: 64K    chunk_size: 16M     num_reg: 3 
>     lose cover RAM: 0G Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [
>   0.000000] New variable MTRRs Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] reg 0, base: 0GB, range: 2GB, type WB Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] reg 1, base: 2039MB, range: 1MB,
>   type UC Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] reg 2,
>   base: 2040MB, range: 8MB, type UC Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop
>   kernel: [    0.000000] found SMP MP-table at [mem
>   0x000fe200-0x000fe20f] mapped at [ffff8800000fe200] Dec 13 13:12:48
>   kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] initial memory mapped: [mem
>   0x00000000-0x1fffffff] Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [
>   0.000000] Base memory trampoline at [ffff880000089000] 89000 size 24576 Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000]
>   init_memory_mapping: [mem 0x00000000-0x7f6fffff] Dec 13 13:12:48
>   kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000]  [mem 0x00000000-0x7f5fffff] page
>   2M Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000]  [mem
>   0x7f600000-0x7f6fffff] page 4k Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [
>   0.000000] kernel direct mapping tables up to 0x7f6fffff @ [mem 0x1fffc000-0x1fffffff] Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [
>   0.000000] RAMDISK: [mem 0x36100000-0x37077fff] Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] ACPI: RSDP 00000000000fe020 00014
>   (v00 INTEL ) Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000]
>   ACPI: RSDT 000000007f6fd038 00050 (v01 INTEL  D945GCR  00000045
>   01000013) Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] ACPI:
>   FACP 000000007f6fc000 00074 (v01 INTEL  D945GCR  00000045 MSFT
>   01000013) Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] ACPI:
>   DSDT 000000007f6f8000 03CE6 (v01 INTEL  D945GCR  00000045 MSFT
>   01000013) Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] ACPI:
>   FACS 000000007f6a8000 00040 Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [
>   0.000000] ACPI: APIC 000000007f6f7000 00078 (v01 INTEL  D945GCR  00000045 MSFT 01000013) Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [
>   0.000000] ACPI: WDDT 000000007f6f6000 00040 (v01 INTEL  D945GCR  00000045 MSFT 01000013) Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [
>   0.000000] ACPI: MCFG 000000007f6f5000 0003C (v01 INTEL  D945GCR  00000045 MSFT 01000013) Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [
>   0.000000] ACPI: ASF! 000000007f6f4000 000A6 (v32 INTEL  D945GCR  00000045 MSFT 01000013) Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [
>   0.000000] ACPI: HPET 000000007f6f3000 00038 (v01 INTEL  D945GCR  00000045 MSFT 01000013) Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [
>   0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 000000007f6f2000 001BC (v01 INTEL     CpuPm 00000045 MSFT 01000013) Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [
>   0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 000000007f6f1000 001B7 (v01 INTEL   Cpu0Ist 00000045 MSFT 01000013) Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [
>   0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 000000007f6f0000 001B7 (v01 INTEL   Cpu1Ist 00000045 MSFT 01000013) Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [
>   0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 000000007f6ef000 001B7 (v01 INTEL   Cpu2Ist 00000045 MSFT 01000013) Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [
>   0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 000000007f6ee000 001B7 (v01 INTEL   Cpu3Ist 00000045 MSFT 01000013) Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [
>   0.000000] ACPI: Local APIC address 0xfee00000 Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] No NUMA configuration found Dec
>   13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] Faking a node at [mem
>   0x0000000000000000-0x000000007f6fffff] Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop
>   kernel: [    0.000000] Initmem setup node 0 [mem
>   0x00000000-0x7f6fffff] Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [
>   0.000000]   NODE_DATA [mem 0x7f6a3000-0x7f6a7fff] Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] 
>   [ffffea0000000000-ffffea0001ffffff] PMD ->
>   [ffff88007c400000-ffff88007e3fffff] on node 0 Dec 13 13:12:48
>   kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] Zone ranges: Dec 13 13:12:48
>   kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000]   DMA      [mem
>   0x00010000-0x00ffffff] Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [
>   0.000000]   DMA32    [mem 0x01000000-0xffffffff] Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000]   Normal   empty Dec 13 13:12:48
>   kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] Movable zone start for each node
>   Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] Early memory node
>   ranges Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000]   node
>   0: [mem 0x00010000-0x0008efff] Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [
>   0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x00100000-0x7e5f4fff] Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000]   node   0: [mem
>   0x7e6d1000-0x7f573fff] Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [
>   0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x7f57c000-0x7f60afff] Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000]   node   0: [mem
>   0x7f60f000-0x7f6a7fff] Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [
>   0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x7f6ea000-0x7f6edfff] Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000]   node   0: [mem
>   0x7f6ff000-0x7f6fffff] Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [
>   0.000000] On node 0 totalpages: 521540 Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000]   DMA zone: 64 pages used for memmap Dec 13
>   13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000]   DMA zone: 6 pages
>   reserved Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000]   DMA
>   zone: 3897 pages, LIFO batch:0 Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [
>   0.000000]   DMA32 zone: 8092 pages used for memmap Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000]   DMA32 zone: 509481 pages, LIFO
>   batch:31 Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] ACPI:
>   PM-Timer IO Port: 0x408 Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [
>   0.000000] ACPI: Local APIC address 0xfee00000 Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x01]
>   lapic_id[0x00] enabled) Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [
>   0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x02] lapic_id[0x01] enabled) Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC
>   (acpi_id[0x03] lapic_id[0x82] disabled) Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop
>   kernel: [    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x04] lapic_id[0x83]
>   disabled) Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] ACPI:
>   LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x01] dfl dfl lint[0x1]) Dec 13 13:12:48
>   kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x02]
>   dfl dfl lint[0x1]) Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [
>   0.000000] ACPI: IOAPIC (id[0x02] address[0xfec00000] gsi_base[0]) Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] IOAPIC[0]: apic_id 2,
>   version 32, address 0xfec00000, GSI 0-23 Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop
>   kernel: [    0.000000] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 0 global_irq 2
>   dfl dfl) Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] ACPI:
>   INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 9 global_irq 9 high level) Dec 13 13:12:48
>   kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] ACPI: IRQ0 used by override. Dec
>   13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] ACPI: IRQ2 used by
>   override. Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] ACPI:
>   IRQ9 used by override. Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [
>   0.000000] Using ACPI (MADT) for SMP configuration information Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] ACPI: HPET id:
>   0x8086a201 base: 0xfed00000 Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [
>   0.000000] smpboot: Allowing 4 CPUs, 2 hotplug CPUs Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] nr_irqs_gsi: 40 Dec 13 13:12:48
>   kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory:
>   000000000008f000 - 00000000000a0000 Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop
>   kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000000a0000
>   - 00000000000e0000 Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000000e0000 - 0000000000100000 Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000]
>   PM: Registered nosave memory: 000000007e5f5000 - 000000007e6d1000 Dec
>   13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave
>   memory: 000000007f574000 - 000000007f57c000 Dec 13 13:12:48
>   kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory:
>   000000007f60b000 - 000000007f60f000 Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop
>   kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: 000000007f6a8000
>   - 000000007f6ea000 Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: 000000007f6ee000 - 000000007f6ff000 Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000]
>   e820: [mem 0x80000000-0xfff7ffff] available for PCI devices Dec 13
>   13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] Booting paravirtualized
>   kernel on bare hardware Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [
>   0.000000] setup_percpu: NR_CPUS:256 nr_cpumask_bits:256 nr_cpu_ids:4 nr_node_ids:1 Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000]
>   PERCPU: Embedded 28 pages/cpu @ffff88007f200000 s84928 r8192 d21568
>   u524288 Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000]
>   pcpu-alloc: s84928 r8192 d21568 u524288 alloc=1*2097152 Dec 13
>   13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: [0] 0 1 2 3 
>   Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists
>   in Node order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 513378 Dec 13
>   13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] Policy zone: DMA32 Dec
>   13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] Kernel command line:
>   BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-34-generic
>   root=UUID=ad695616-caeb-451b-b8bf-707ba6232e39 ro quiet splash
>   vt.handoff=7 Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] PID
>   hash table entries: 4096 (order: 3, 32768 bytes) Dec 13 13:12:48
>   kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] __ex_table already sorted,
>   skipping sort Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000]
>   Checking aperture... Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [
>   0.000000] No AGP bridge found Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] Calgary: detecting Calgary via BIOS EBDA area Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] Calgary: Unable to
>   locate Rio Grande table in EBDA - bailing! Dec 13 13:12:48
>   kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] Memory: 2021260k/2087936k
>   available (7172k kernel code, 1776k absent, 64900k reserved, 6071k
>   data, 1016k init) Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000]
>   SLUB: Genslabs=15, HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=4,
>   Nodes=1 Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000]
>   Hierarchical RCU implementation. Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel:
>   [    0.000000]    RCU dyntick-idle grace-period acceleration is enabled.
>   Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000]  RCU restricting
>   CPUs from NR_CPUS=256 to nr_cpu_ids=4. Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop
>   kernel: [    0.000000] NR_IRQS:16640 nr_irqs:712 16 Dec 13 13:12:48
>   kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] Console: colour dummy device
>   80x25 Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] console
>   [tty0] enabled Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000]
>   allocated 8388608 bytes of page_cgroup Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop
>   kernel: [    0.000000] please try 'cgroup_disable=memory' option if
>   you don't want memory cgroups Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [ 
>   0.000000] hpet clockevent registered Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] tsc: Fast TSC calibration using PIT Dec 13
>   13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] tsc: Detected 2194.678
>   MHz processor Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.004005]
>   Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer
>   frequency.. 4389.35 BogoMIPS (lpj=8778712) Dec 13 13:12:48
>   kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.004010] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum:
>   301 Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.004043] Security
>   Framework initialized Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [
>   0.004063] AppArmor: AppArmor initialized Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.004064] Yama: becoming mindful. Dec 13 13:12:48
>   kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.004302] Dentry cache hash table entries:
>   262144 (order: 9, 2097152 bytes) Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel:
>   [    0.005536] Inode-cache hash table entries: 131072 (order: 8,
>   1048576 bytes) Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.006226]
>   Mount-cache hash table entries: 256 Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop
>   kernel: [    0.006497] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct Dec 13
>   13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.006502] Initializing cgroup
>   subsys memory Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.006514]
>   Initializing cgroup subsys devices Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop
>   kernel: [    0.006516] Initializing cgroup subsys freezer Dec 13
>   13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.006518] Initializing cgroup
>   subsys blkio Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.006521]
>   Initializing cgroup subsys perf_event Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop
>   kernel: [    0.006524] Initializing cgroup subsys hugetlb Dec 13
>   13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.006559] CPU: Physical Processor
>   ID: 0 Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.006561] CPU:
>   Processor Core ID: 0 Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [
>   0.006563] mce: CPU supports 6 MCE banks Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.006573] CPU0: Thermal monitoring enabled (TM2) Dec 13
>   13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.006578] process: using mwait in
>   idle threads Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.006584] Last
>   level iTLB entries: 4KB 128, 2MB 4, 4MB 4 Dec 13 13:12:48
>   kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.006584] Last level dTLB entries: 4KB 256,
>   2MB 0, 4MB 32 Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.006584]
>   tlb_flushall_shift: -1 Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [
>   0.006711] Freeing SMP alternatives: 24k freed Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.009991] ACPI: Core revision 20121018 Dec
>   13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.013634] ftrace: allocating
>   29364 entries in 115 pages Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [
>   0.024503] ..TIMER: vector=0x30 apic1=0 pin1=2 apic2=-1 pin2=-1 Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.065610] smpboot: CPU0: Intel(R)
>   Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     E4500  @ 2.20GHz (fam: 06, model: 0f, stepping:
>   0d) Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.068000] Performance
>   Events: PEBS fmt0+, 4-deep LBR, Core2 events, Intel PMU driver. Dec 13
>   13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.068000] perf_event_intel: PEBS
>   disabled due to CPU errata Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [
>   0.068000] ... version:                2 Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.068000] ... bit width:              40 Dec 13 13:12:48
>   kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.068000] ... generic registers:      2 Dec
>   13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.068000] ... value mask:
>   000000ffffffffff Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.068000]
>   ... max period:             000000007fffffff Dec 13 13:12:48
>   kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.068000] ... fixed-purpose events:   3 Dec
>   13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.068000] ... event mask:
>   0000000700000003 Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.068000]
>   smpboot: Booting Node   0, Processors  #1 Dec 13 13:12:48
>   kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.078404] Brought up 2 CPUs Dec 13 13:12:48
>   kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.078411] smpboot: Total of 2 processors
>   activated (8778.71 BogoMIPS) Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [
>   0.078532] NMI watchdog: enabled on all CPUs, permanently consumes one hw-PMU counter. Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.080006]
>   devtmpfs: initialized Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [
>   0.081553] EVM: security.selinux Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.081555] EVM: security.SMACK64 Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop
>   kernel: [    0.081557] EVM: security.capability Dec 13 13:12:48
>   kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.081571] PM: Registering ACPI NVS region
>   [mem 0x7e5f5000-0x7e6d0fff] (901120 bytes) Dec 13 13:12:48
>   kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.081571] PM: Registering ACPI NVS region
>   [mem 0x7f6a8000-0x7f6e9fff] (270336 bytes) Dec 13 13:12:48
>   kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.081571] regulator-dummy: no parameters
>   Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.081571] NET: Registered
>   protocol family 16 Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [
>   0.081571] ACPI: bus type pci registered Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.081571] PCI: MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-7f] at
>   [mem 0xf0000000-0xf7ffffff] (base 0xf0000000) Dec 13 13:12:48
>   kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.081571] PCI: not using MMCONFIG Dec 13
>   13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.081571] PCI: Using configuration
>   type 1 for base access Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [
>   0.084085] bio: create slab  at 0 Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.084085] ACPI: Added _OSI(Module Device) Dec 13 13:12:48
>   kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.084085] ACPI: Added _OSI(Processor
>   Device) Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.084085] ACPI:
>   Added _OSI(3.0 _SCP Extensions) Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel:
>   [    0.084085] ACPI: Added _OSI(Processor Aggregator Device) Dec 13
>   13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.084784] ACPI: EC: Look up EC in
>   DSDT Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.086442] ACPI:
>   Interpreter enabled Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [
>   0.086447] ACPI: (supports S0 S1 S3 S4 S5) Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.086465] ACPI: Using IOAPIC for interrupt
>   routing Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.086479] PCI:
>   MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-7f] at [mem 0xf0000000-0xf7ffffff]
>   (base 0xf0000000) Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.086799]
>   PCI: MMCONFIG at [mem 0xf0000000-0xf7ffffff] reserved in ACPI
>   motherboard resources Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [
>   0.086803] PCI: MMCONFIG for 0000 [bus00-3f] at [mem 0xf0000000-0xf3ffffff] (base 0xf0000000) (size reduced!) Dec 13
>   13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.098542] ACPI: No dock devices
>   found. Dec 13 13:12:48 kamil-desktop kernel: [    0.098547] PCI: Using
>   host bridge windows from ACPI; if necessary, use "pci=nocrs" and

Answer (score 1):

Try to install `blueman` with `sudo apt-get install blueman` in `terminal`. I have problems with sending files too. When I'm using `blueman` it isn't any problems.